# error: not found: value SchemaConverters

Tags: databricks, spark-avro

I am using `databricks` for my use-case where I have to convert `avro` schema to `struct type`. When I searched, it says `spark-avro` has `SchemaConverters` to do that. However, I am using `spark-avro-2.11-4.0` library and when I use `SchemaConverters`, I get

> "error: not found: value SchemaConverters".

Please help on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Which [Databricks Runtime version](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/cluster-images/index.html) are you using for your cluster?

Comment: I am using Databricks 3.4 (includes Apache Spark 2.2.0, Scala 2.11).